# store X and Y coordinates

Tags: java, coordinates

Hi im new to this site and need help with a program im working on. the problem im having is that i cant seem to store string and two integers (as the coordinates). i have looked at other code but dont see how the values are stored. below is the code ive been using. the code seems to be fine but when trying to stored the values i cant put multiply integers. thanks for your time

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class map {

    class Coords {
        int x;
        int y;

        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            Coords c = (Coords) o;
            return c.x == x && c.y == y;
        }

        public Coords(int x, int y) {
            super();
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int hashCode() {
            return new Integer(x + "0" + y);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        HashMap<Coords, Character> map = new HashMap<Coords, Character>();
        map.put(new coords(65, 72), "Dan");
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you use such a complex hash code algorithm? Why don't you just use the good old `x + (some prime number) * y`, e.g. `x + 31*y`? Also, note that your `equals` implementation doesn't take `null` values or illegal casts into account.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens I thought this hashCode was not complex, but rather, simpler in comparison to prime number hashing, correct? It also has the upside of plainly showing the coordinates, separated by a 0.

Comment: @K_7 Perhaps it's less complex for humans to read, but it's definitely more complex (as in: more work) for the computer. For performance-critical code, you want `hashCode` to do as little as possible (while still giving a decent hash). OPs version does string concatenation and number parsing, whereas the prime number hashing is just one integer addition and one integer multiplication.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There seems to be several issues:

- "Dan" is a `String`, not a `Character`
- case is important in Java (`new coords(65,72)` should be `new Coords(65,72)`)
- Coords needs to be static to be instantiated without a reference to an instance the enclosing map class.

This should work:

```
static class Coords {
    ...
}

Map<Coords, String> map = new HashMap<Coords, String>();
map.put(new Coords(65, 72), "Dan");
```

ps: although you are allowed to name a local variable `map` within a `class map`, it is not a good idea to have such name collision. In Java, classes generally start in upper case, so you could rename your class Map. But it happens that Map is a standard class in Java. So call your class Main or Test or whatever is relevant. ;-)

Comment: Also `Coords` is ***inner class*** so only way to create instance of that class is via instance of outer class. To remove that problem it may be good idea to convert it in ***nested class*** by adding static modifier (`static class Coords{/*...*/}`).

Comment: @Pshemo Absolutely, I made it static in my test but forgot to include that in my answer. Well spotted.

Answer (score 22):

There is a class in java called Class Point.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html

This is the same information provided on Java docs API 10:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html

A point representing a location in (x,y) coordinate space, specified in integer precision.

You can see an example, and also other important topics related in this link: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Pointclass.htm

```
import java.awt.Point;

class PointSetter {

  public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    Point location = new Point(4, 13);

    System.out.println("Starting location:");
    System.out.println("X equals " + location.x);
    System.out.println("Y equals " + location.y);

    System.out.println("\nMoving to (7, 6)");
    location.x = 7;
    location.y = 6;

    System.out.println("\nEnding location:");
    System.out.println("X equals " + location.x);
    System.out.println("Y equals " + location.y);
  }
}
```

I hope this can help you!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @assylias

1. Make you `inner class` `stati`c in order to insert new objects like you have or `new Outer().new Inner()` .
2. Take care of [Java Naming Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

**Code like:**

```
public class XYTest {
    static class Coords {
        int x;
        int y;

        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            Coords c = (Coords) o;
            return c.x == x && c.y == y;
        }

        public Coords(int x, int y) {
            super();
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int hashCode() {
            return new Integer(x + "0" + y);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        HashMap<Coords, String> map = new HashMap<Coords, String>();

        map.put(new Coords(65, 72), "Dan");

        map.put(new Coords(68, 78), "Amn");
        map.put(new Coords(675, 89), "Ann");

        System.out.println(map.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. just wondering how i would print out the Coords as when i try it doesnt work thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
package Lecture3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class lecture9 {

    private int nInleste;

    public lecture9() {/*
                         * tabell/ // T/*chapter 6 in the books.
                         **/
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nInleste = 3;
        double[] tall = new double[nInleste];
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nInleste; i++) {
            System.out.println("Leste en tall!");
            tall[i] = inn.nextDouble();
            sum += tall[i];
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        double snitt = nInleste / nInleste;
        System.out.println("Gjennomsnittsverdien:" + snitt);
        for (int i = 0; i < nInleste; i++) {
            double aavik = tall[i] - snitt;
            int avvivk = 0;
            System.out.println(i + 1 + " Tal sitt avvik fra gjennomsnittet " + avvivk);

        }
    }/* end of the main methods */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have problem with your code you can try this , simple code to store string and two `int` values into a `map`

```
class MyCoord{
    private int X;
    private int Y;

    public MyCoord() {
        this(0,0);
    }        
    public MyCoord(int X, int Y) {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return X;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return Y;
    }
    public void setX(int X) {
        this.X = X;
    }
    public void setY(int Y) {
        this.Y = Y;
    }
}
```

//main class begins

```
public class  PointDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map <String,MyCoord> multiplePoints=new HashMap<String, MyCoord>();
        multiplePoints.put("point1", new MyCoord(10, 20));
        multiplePoints.put("point2", new MyCoord(100, 2000));

        MyCoord coord=multiplePoints.get("point1");
        System.out.println(coord.getX() +" : "+coord.getY());              
    }
}
```