# How to check if the exact elements in an array are contained within an array stored in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` of [2] arrays (coordinates) - how do I check if, e.g. arr[1, 2], an array containing the same elements in the same order is contained within the list.

i.e. Are coordinates [1, 2] contained within `ArrayList`

I created a test below which proves my method wrong.

```
ArrayList<int[]> arrList = new ArrayList<>();

int[] arr1 = new int[]{1, 2};

int[] arr2 = new int[]{1, 2};

arrList.add(arr1);

System.out.println("test array contains? " + arrList.contains(arr2));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are discovering a `List<int[]>` is rather inconvenient. The `contains` method for `List` checks with `.equals` to see if an object is contained in the `List`. However `arr1.equals(arr2);` is the same as `arr1 == arr2`, (The implementation is literally `return (this == obj);`). This checks to see if the objects are in the same memory location, which isn't what you want. You want to use [`Arrays.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(int[],%20int[])):

```
arraylist.stream().anyMatch(arr -> Arrays.equals(arr, arr2));
```

Or you could change it to a different data structure than `List<int[]>`. I suggest taking an OOP approach and creating a `Coordinate` class and then having a `List<Coordinate>` (Don't forget to override `.equals()`!)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721013/store-x-and-y-coordinates) is a thread about creating a `Coordinate` class that might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. `arr1` and `arr2` are different instance though they contain same value so `arrList.contains(arr2)` returns `false`.

To compare value you need to implement your own function.

```
    boolean contains = false;
    for (int[] arr : arrList) {
        if (arr2[0] == arr[0] && arr2[1] == arr[1]) {
            contains = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("test array contains? " + contains);
```

Here we are iterating through `arrList` if it contains an array with the same value of `arr2`. If it does, we are setting true to `contains` & exiting the loop.